# Sorting distinct elements in an array

Tags: algorithm

I have a number of distinct elements in an array and want to find those items first before sorting the array. I was thinking of using a hash table to find the elements, but is that possible since I then have to access the table to get the elements again? Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you only have a couple of duplicates, then you could sort then remove them; otherwise the method you have in mind should be enough.

Comment: thank you, yes there are a lot of duplicates

Comment: Most algorithms are written in highly optimized standard libraries-- please state your platform so we don't recreate an optimized wheel.

Comment: This is just a hw/theory based question.